# How to select FROM {commerce_product} p WHERE p.field_TERMFIELD = $given_tid and the resulted p.product_id is referenced on a given nid

Tags: database

Known values:

- The nid of a node that has reference to more than one commerce_product
- The tid from the field_TERMFIELD field attached to the commerce_product entity

commerce_product entity is referenced on the node entity via a multivalued entity reference field. When my known node has more than one referenced commerce product, I gotta figure out which one of those referenced products has a given tid.

A solution via either `db_select()` or `EntityFieldQuery()` are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it figured out:

```
$query = db_select('commerce_product', 'p');
$query->join('field_data_field_TERMFIELD', 't', 't.entity_id = p.product_id');
// This is the product reference field table. This field is attached to our node.
$query->join('field_data_field_product_reference', 'pr', 'pr.field_product_reference_product_id = p.product_id');

$query
  // This is the product_id we are looking for.
  ->fields('p', array('product_id'))

  ->condition('field_TERMFIELD_tid', $tid)
  ->condition('pr.entity_type', 'node')
  ->condition('pr.entity_id', $nid);

 $result = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

By joining the **node** and **product fields tables** that are required

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query -> leftJoin('field_data_field_product', 'seat', "seat.entity_id = n.nid AND seat.entity_type = 'node' AND seat.bundle = 'seat'");
```

In your case you need to inverse the process to get data from product table...